# How to read file: Properties > Details > Content > Pages e.g. for a word document

Tags: java, file, properties

When you right-click on any file in Windows you can select "Properties" in the menu.
In the upcoming dialog box you see a tab: "Details". There you can find a lot of properties (Name, Type, Owner, ...)!
My question is:

**How can I read this file properties?**

I've tried it years ago and it was not possible for me. I think with Java 1.7 it might be possible. I have tried UserDefinedAttributeView but it's not working.

I have tried the following: I see in the Details Tab the Section "File" and the property "Name". But I get an Exception if I execute the below code:

Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: D:\test.txt:File.Name

And text.txt exists ;)

```
    Path path = new File("D:\\test.txt").toPath();        
    UserDefinedFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path,   UserDefinedFileAttributeView.class);
    String name = "File.Name";
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(view.size(name));        
    view.read(name, buf);
    buf.flip();
    String value = Charset.defaultCharset().decode(buf).toString();
```

Many Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it just calling the new attribute "user." and getting it with the same string "user.". I'm not sure that "File." works, anyway check the user's defined attributes list by the command "view.list().toString()".

Hoping to have help you (..even if quite late...)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem was not that it wasn't finding `test.txt`, but it wasn't finding `File.Name`.  Your code snippet has `....view.size(name)`, where `name = "File.Name"` - so it is trying to find the size of a file `File.Name` and isn't finding that.  Which is because you don't intend `File.Name` to be a filename, you intend it to be the name of the property you're looking for.

(That said, I'm also trying to find a solution that works for getting property values from the Details tab, within a Java program...  All I've found so far requires JNA.)